# Simple PHP strpos function not working, why?

Tags: php, strpos

Why isn't this standalone code working:

```
$link = 'https://google.com';
$unacceptables = array('https:','.doc','.pdf', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.bmp', '.png');

foreach ($unacceptables as $unacceptable) {
        if (strpos($link, $unacceptable) === true) {
            echo 'Unacceptable Found<br />';
        } else {
            echo 'Acceptable!<br />';
        }
}
```

It's printing acceptable every time even though https is contained within the `$link` variable.

Comment: A comment for those who can't get strpos to work: be careful not to confuse `strpos( $haystack, $needle )` with the other function `in_array( $needle, $haystack )`. As you can see, **the order of the arguments is reversed**.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

When in doubt, read [the docs](https://www.php.net/strpos):

> [strpos] Returns the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the haystack string.

So you want to try something more like:

```
// ...
if (strpos($link, $unacceptable) !== false) {
```

Because otherwise `strpos` is returning a number, and you're looking for a boolean `true`.

Answer (score 15):

[strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) does not return true when it finds a match, it returns the position of the first matching string. Watchout, if the match is a the beginning of the string it will return an index of zero which will compare as equal to false unless you use the === operator.

Answer (score 8):

Your failure condition is wrong.

strpos returns false if match is not found, so you need to explicitly check

```
if (strpos($link, $unacceptable) !== false) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Strpos always return position like you search "httpsL" in your string('https://google.com';) then it return 0th position and PHP evaluate it as false.

please see this link:(Hope its very usefull for you):
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 1):

strpos

function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE.

So I did like this

```
if (strpos($link, $unacceptable) !== false) {
    //Code
}
```