# search php array for string and return the key?

Tags: php, arrays, search, strpos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple PHP strpos function not working, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858927/simple-php-strpos-function-not-working-why)

I'm trying to search a php array for a certain string in a value and return the key.. but having no luck so far. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but here's what I've done so far..

My array (called options):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Blue^35cm^10
    [1] => Pink^35cm, 40cm, 50cm^10, 3, 5
    [1] => Green^35cm, 50cm^3, 2
)
```

I'm trying to find Pink in the following code and trying to return the key..

```
foreach ($options as $key => $value) :
    if (strpos($value,'Pink')) :
        echo $key;
    endif;
endforeach;
```

But it doesn't seem to be working? Any help would be great!

Comment: Try `strstr()`, or check the return type of `strpos`.

Comment: Also, read the big **Warning** section on this page - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strpos` function returns the position as an integer, in your example, Pink would return as 0.

You need to check that `strpos` comes back as anything other than `false`, like so:

```
if (strpos($value, 'Pink') !== false)
```